# Jakarta Server Pages doesnt find property

Tags: java, jsp, web, tomcat

I'm trying to use jsp with Java and therefore I created the function `getBestellung()` . This function connects to my database and get's some entries out of it. The method itselfs works, but when I try to get the return value I get the following error on my Tomcat server: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property [data] in a bean of type [com.example.CSA_Server.DBFunc]`

This is the Class looks like:

```
import com.example.CSA_Server.Bestellung;

import org.omg.CORBA.PUBLIC_MEMBER;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBFunc implements secrets{

    public static Connection conn() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Verbindung wurde hergestellt");
        return conn;
    }

    public static String getBestellung() throws SQLException{
        Connection conn = conn();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Bestellung";
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
        Bestellung b1 = null;
        while(result.next()) {
            long bID = result.getLong("B-ID");
            long kID = result.getLong("K-ID");
            b1 = new Bestellung(bID, kID);
        }
        String string = String.valueOf(b1);
        conn.close();
        //System.out.println(string);
        return string;
    }


}
```

The JSP looks the like:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<jsp:useBean id="time" class="com.example.CSA_Server.TimeServlet" scope="request" />
<jsp:useBean id="data" class="com.example.CSA_Server.DBFunc" scope="request" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= "Hello World!" %>
</h1>
<p>Das ist ein Probetext</p>
<br/>
<a href="hello-servlet">Hello Servlet</a>
<LI>Hallo du da</LI>
<LI><jsp:getProperty name="time" property="time"/></LI>
<LI>Du bist: <%request.getParameter("name");%></LI>

<p><jsp:getProperty name="data" property="data"/></p>
<p>Data: <%request.getParameter("data");%></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Most of the time, when I refresh the page there is no error. When there is no error the following value is showed: `class com.example.CSA_Server.DBFunc`

After refreshing multiple times I get the mentioned error.

Is there an issue with the `getBestellung()` function or is the jsp Syntax wrong?

Comment: This code  <%request.getParameter("name");%> and  the other one like it  are  scriptlets.   Scriptlets don't print anything.  Also, the way you have them written,  they don't do anything.  Did you  mean to make them  "JSP expressions" ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the `<jsp:getProperty>` tag properly: the attribute `property` must be the name of JavaBean property you want to retrieve (cf. e.g. [this tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-setProperty-and-jsp-getProperty-action-tag)). In your case you want to retrieve the property *"bestellung"*, so use:

```xml
<jsp:getProperty name="data" property="bestellung"/>
```

**Remark**: You could also use the EL expression `${data.bestellung}` instead.

Comment: I changed it, but now I get the following error: ```org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property [bestellung] in a bean of type [com.example.CSA_Server.DBFunc]``` . It also still behaves like I mentioned before. So sometimes it showes ```class com.example.CSA_Server.DBFunc``` and sometimes the error.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that `getBestellung` is declared `static`. JSP is looking for an **instance** method with signature `public String getBestellung()`. You should remove the `static` modifier.

Comment: Okay, I also changed that. Now I'm getting the same error or the page without the "class com.example.CSA_Server.DBFunc" . When I print out the result I get "Bestellung{bID=2, kID=2}", but this doesnt show up on the webpage.,,,

Comment: Check if your Tomcat is not running the old code, by emptying the `work` directory.